# Changing the fate

Tags: the-room-3

After finishing the game and got imprisoned, now I'd like to escape the labyrinth. I reached the point where I got the cross shaped key, now I have no idea where to go next, anyone could give me some help?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The cross shaped keyhole is behind the iron bars from the very first room. You have to find a crank to open those doors. The fortune teller will help.

Comment: That's probaly not enough on itself to a changed faith, but it's a start.

Comment: I don't want to give it away too much. The game is only fun if you figure it out on your own.

Comment: @Mark, [how do I consult the fortune teller](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/258649/28171)?