# How do I find the alternate endings in The Room Three?

Tags: the-room-3

I got to the first ending, and went back to Change My Fate, but I don't know what to work on.  I solved a couple more puzzles, but there doesn't seem to be anything left that I have any way to manipulate.  I don't want a walkthrough, just a hint about where I should be looking for something to do.

In my inventory, I have a screwdriver, the Craftsman's key, and a blank wax cylinder.

Items that I think I can do more with, but I don't think I have the right tools for yet...

I know I need a crank for this grate in the first room:

[image: grate latch]

I don't know how to open the big compartment in this desk, although I got both the top drawers open:

[image: desk]

The design in the middle of that desk looks like it might be manipulated:

[image: desk middle]

I can open & close the coin slot of this fortune teller, but I don't have a coin:

[image: fortune teller]

I found two record players, but I can't use them:

[image: record player 1] [image: record player 2]

There's an old safe:

[image: safe]

And there's something on the railing next to the safe (and something else across the center gap):

[image: by safe] [image: across from safe]

This machine needs one more blue crystal:

[image: crystal machine]

And there's something embedded in a tree:

[image]

But none of these items seem to be manipulable in any useful way with the tools I have.

Comment: I'm not immediately clear on whether you're asking for strategies or solutions.  Solutions can be seen here (spoilers, obviously): http://www.appunwrapper.com/2015/11/06/the-room-three-3-bonus-puzzles-endings-walkthrough-guide/ Strategies, I dunno...

Comment: I'm looking for a hint.  Where should I be looking to make progress?  There doesn't seem to be anything I can do.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've now found all 4 endings.

The first thing I needed to do was search one of the upper drawers of the desk very carefully.

There's another focus spot related to the item embedded in the tree that I had overlooked.

This device:

[image: railing device]

can be manipulated without tools.  However, its effect is very subtle at first.  Keep trying to move your finger on the gold part, and eventually you'll figure out what it does.  Then you have to figure out what you have to make it do.

One more tip—when you get to the point when you're ready to dial on this device:

[image: record player with dial]

you must put your finger on the digit you're trying to dial and turn until the dial stops (it won't go too far).  If you stop turning before the dial locks, it doesn't register.